# How does faked DNS manage to downgrade preloaded HSTS?

Tags: dns, spoofing, hsts

Yesterday, in a bid to entertain myself for a while, I was playing around with DNS servers. I set up a DNS server locally, which I then set as my primary DNS server. Within it, I added some records that overrode what would otherwise be existing domains: I pointed Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc, at 127.0.0.1 (`google.com. 60 IN A 127.0.0.1`), where I had a web server running.

To my surprise, it *worked*. Visiting `http://google.com` returned the web page as served by my local web server.

Thing is... `google.com` is supposed to have preloaded HSTS on it. I was under the impression that my browser should *know* that `google.com` is meant to only ever be sent requests via HTTPS, and hence hitting the HTTP version and getting a local page should not work.

Where are my assumptions wrong?

Comment: Could you revert the DNS, open the Developer Tools, go to the Network Inspection, and open http://www.google.com via HTTP? You have to see a `307 Internal Redirect` on Chrome. If not, something is wrong.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what browser you were using.

Answer (score 5):

The domains `google.com` and `www.google.com` are not HSTS-preloaded. You can check that [here](https://hstspreload.org/?domain=google.com). They don't even initially send a HSTS header.

Other subdomains of Google are preloaded, e.g. [`accounts.google.com`](https://hstspreload.org/?domain=accounts.google.com).

Your assumption is correct that for a preloaded domain, accessing the site over plain HTTP in your browser should not be possible, regardless where you point the DNS. You simply checked the wrong domain.

Comment: The same held for all the domains I listed, though, and Twitter is certainly HSTS-preloaded.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Which browser (and version) are you using? Does it work with *any* preloaded domain? You may want to consider filing a bug report.

Comment: As of the end of July 2016, www.google.com does have HSTS: https://security.googleblog.com/2016/07/bringing-hsts-to-wwwgooglecom.html

Comment: @jub0bs Thanks for keeping things up-to-date. However, I just checked, and it seems like things haven't changed: https://hstspreload.org/?domain=google.com https://hstspreload.org/?domain=www.google.com

Comment: @Arminius Just to clarify, they have (non-preloaded) HSTS on the `www` subdomain; the base domain indeed still isn't preloaded.